# Regex not parsing address from email

Tags: regex, parsing, webhooks, make.com

I am trying to create a scenario on integromat/Make where I would forward an email and parse the data from there.

Below you can see the information that I want to parse.

Name: Test Hello

Email: test@gmail.com

Phone: 04111111

Purchase property address: Unit 111, 12 Heydon Street, Mosman NSW 2088

Current property address: 34 Test Street, TestR NSW 2031

My current regex is

```
Name:\s?\n*(?<firstname>[\w\S-']*)\s*(?<surname>[\w \t\f\v\S]*?)\s*(\nSurname:)*\s*Email:\s?\n*(?<email>[\S]*[@]\S*).*\n*Phone:\s?\n*(?<phone>[\d \t\f\v\[\]()-+]*)\n*(Purchase Property Address:)\s?\n*(?<propertyaddress[\w\W]*).*\n*(Current property address:)?\s?\n*(?<message>[\w\W]*?)
```

However, it only works for the Name, email and phone. It is not parsing the text for Purchase property address and Current property address.

Comment: You have some bugs in your character classes: Dashes should be first or last, otherwise it's considered a *range* operator (eg `[a-z]`), so `[\d \t\f\v\[\]()-+]` which includes all characters between`)` and `+`, should be `[\d \t\f\v\[\]()+-]`.

Comment: This part `Purchase Property` starts with an uppercase char in the pattern, but is lowercase in the text, and you should close the named capture group `(?<propertyaddress>` You also use a lot of optional parts for newlines etc..and the last part for message should not be non greedy. See https://regex101.com/r/Q9gu4B/1 Is this a fixed format, and are there parts that can span multiple lines?